# Como consigo comparar os seguintes intervalos no excel

Tags: excel-vba, microsoft-excel

Eu tenho uma coluna que vai receber diversos valores (coluna AK):
[coluna que vai receber os valores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS7lm.png)

Tenho também uma coluna com valores predefinidos(coluna AS):
[Coluna com os valores predefinidos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl31M.png)

E não estou a encontrar nenhuma solução para comparar todos os números de AK com AS de forma independente da linha.
Eu queria colorir do fundo das células da coluna AS que aparecessem na coluna na coluna AK independentemente da linha.

Answer (score -1):

Nesse caso você deve utilizar uma formatação condicional.
Selecione a coluna AS inteira, vá em formatação condicional, selecione "Nova Regra" e use a fórmula `=PROCV(AS2;AK:AK;1;0)`, defina a cor de fundo que deseja e pronto.
Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: É triste ver como o apoio que damos VOLUNTARIAMENTE é desvalorizado aqui. Eu me dei ao trabalho de ajudar e ao invés de um simples obrigado é isso que ganho. Por mim que o Stackoverflow exploda! Nunca mais perco meu tempo aqui!